# How to add variables in a call to Start-Process

Tags: powershell, variable-substitution

I'm building a PowerShell script to run the following command on various servers:

```
arapx acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\DEV_Refresh\\AccExport.txt\"
```

This code works:

```
Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList 'acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\DEV_Refresh\\AccExport.txt\"'
```

Different servers have different paths for the output file so I tried to set a variable.  But this fails:

```
$Dest_Folder="DEV_Refresh"
Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList 'acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\${Dest_Folder}\\AccExport.txt\"'
```

This fails:

```
$Dest_Folder="DEV_Refresh"
Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList 'acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\$(Dest_Folder)\\AccExport.txt\"'
```

And this fails:

```
$Dest_Folder="DEV_Refresh"
$argumentList = "'acc, Export ExportFile=\""C:\\Temp\\" + $Dest_Folder + "\\AccExport.txt\""'"
Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList $argumentList
```

Can anyone help me get the command to work with a varable?

Comment: Try `Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList ('acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\' + $Dest_Folder + '\\AccExport.txt\"')`

Comment: You almost never need to use start-process, unless you want to wait for the process.  Either don't use quotes, or use the call "&" operator.

Comment: In fact without -wait, start-process will run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from zett42 works:

```
$Dest_Folder="DEV_Refresh"
Start-Process -FilePath '\\<fileserver>\Bin\arapx' -argumentList ('acc, Export ExportFile=\"C:\\Temp\\' + $Dest_Folder + '\\AccExport.txt\"')
```